# Maximally dissimilar subset

Tags: matrix, similarities

Given a N-dimensional similarity matrix, is there an efficient way of finding the subset of size M<N that is maximally dissimilar?

(I guess that the notion of maximally dissimilar is not completely well-defined, so let's say I take as an objective function the sum of the similarity matrix.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The quadratic knapsack problem

This is a special case of the [0-1 quadratic knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_knapsack_problem) (QKP). In the general form of the problem, we have a set of $n$ items, each with a value and weight. We also have an additional value for combining particular pairs of items. The problem is to select a subset of items that maximizes the total value, without exceeding a given weight limit. The problem can be written as:

$$\max_{x \in \{0,1\}^n} \
v^T x + x^T V x
\quad \quad \text{s.t. }
w^T x \le W$$

$x$ is a binary vector indicating which items are selected. Vector $v$ gives the value of each item. $V$ is a matrix where $V_{ij}$ gives the additional value of combining items $i$ and $j$. Vector $w$ gives the weight of each item, and $W$ is the weight limit.

#### Formulating the maximum dissimilarity problem

Your problem can be formulated as an instance of the 0-1 QKP as follows. Set the weight of each item to 1, and the weight limit to $M$. This means we will select $M$ items. Set the value of each item to 0, as we only care about the interaction between items. Set $V$ to the dissimilarity matrix. This means we will try to maximize the sum of dissimilarities between selected items.

#### Solving the problem

The 0-1 QKP is NP hard, so an efficient (polynomial time) algorithm that can solve all instances probably cannot exist. If the problem is only of moderate size, it can be solved using exact search methods like branch-and-bound, which is more efficient than brute force search. However, finding an exact solution is intractable for larger problems. In this case, it's necessary to resort to heuristic search and/or approximation algorithms. The Wikipedia page gives an [overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_knapsack_problem#Solving) of some of these methods.

Comment: Thanks! Since the problem here is a restricted version of the 0-1 QKP, is it possible it's not actually NP?

Comment: @larmor Great question. I don't know the answer, but suspect that this particular restriction won't make life any easier. Here are some handwavy reasons for suspecting this...

Comment: 1) There's still a combinatorial explosion in the feasible set as $n$ increases. 2) The problem still has a similar form (quadratic objective function with linear and 0-1 integer constraints). The integer constraints are what makes things difficult. 3) It doesn't seem like the restriction introduces any special structure we could exploit. For example, the fact that $w=\vec{1}$ alone doesn't seem to buy anything, since other problems have this same constraint but remain NP hard (e.g. best subset regression).